# Spring Security check external JWT roles

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

I have a problem to understand how to check roles from external JWT or if it is possible.

My login page is on another external page and I receive from that a jwt token.
In my project I need to check the validity of that jwt token and restrict some endpoints based on the roles from claims.

I can do it in the jwtFilter somehow but I did not manage to check with ".hasAnyRole()" or ".hasAnyAuthority()" applied on .antMatchers().
I tried to login manualy the user in the spring security but did not manage to have it functional.

This is the configuration of the spring security:

```
http.cors()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/index.html"
            )
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/machines/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
```

I tried to log in manually like this:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwt.getUsername, null,
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(jwt.getRoles()));
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Do you have any idea how to use .hasAnyRole() with having just the jwtToken?

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared how your roles are defined as a claim.

Most common is that you map scopes into authorities, or you can do some custom config to map scopes into roles.

But you have decided to write a custom JWTFilter even though spring security has essentially already a JWTFilter built in that you can customize and had this feature since 2018.

By writing a custom JWTFilter you have basically opted out of the available spring security features and you cannot leverage the built in features like `.hasAuthority`.

Writing custom security is usually considered bad practice.

I would suggest you implement the handling of JWTs in accordance with the spring security reference manual [How JWT Authentication Works in Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture). This can be done by enabling the `oauth2resourceserver` and [Override or Replace The Boot Auto Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot) and then define a [custom JWTDecoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-algorithm).

When this is done you can then [Extract Authorities Manually](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction) and leverage the built in features of spring security.